# How can I view the properties of a ComboBox on an Excel 2007 Worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

A similar question has been asked and solved on this forum, but the solution offered there does not work for me. I have enabled the Developer tab, and clicked Design Mode, but still, right-clicking the control only brings up the Worksheet Properties window.

Furthermore, I have confirmed the default Trusted Macro Settings, and even assigned the file to a Trusted Location, to no avail.

The details are these: I am working with a spreadsheet created in Excel 2003, and imported into Excel 2007 (the 256-column limit having proven too restrictive). Right-clicking the control in the imported version brings up a context menu that includes (along with "Cut", "Copy", "Paste" [grayed-out]/"Grouping", "Order"/ and "Format Control") **"Properties", "View Code"/ "ComboBox Object"**.

Right-clicking the control created in the 2007 version brings up a context menu that does not include "Properties", "View Code"/ "ComboBox Object", but rather, offers "Assign Macro".

I can't help wondering whether the problem lies in some overlooked preference or setting.

Comment: Are they both the same type? Form or activex? Those vary in what's available.

Comment: Thank you, Raystafarian. I don't know how to tell which it is.

Comment: If you right click it and it says combobox options - it's ActiveX. If it just says format control, it's a form control. Sounds like you have form control. Which has less options than activeX, but runs within excel rather than with a library.

Comment: Thank you, Raystafarian. Yes, it must be a form control. How do I place an ActiveX control on the worksheet?

Comment: I'd avoid activeX controls. I always avoid them. What do you  need that they offer that you can't get from a form control other than color changing? [some reading here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20)

Comment: I need access to ComboBox's Bound Column.

Comment: I need access to the Bound Column property. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: The data validation for the combobox?

Comment: I think it's more like the HLOOKUP relationship. Simple solution, though. I didn't realize, in my haste, that there was more than one ComboBox offered on the Tools Menu. It's the ActiveX version I was looking for. I plugged it in, and it works as expected. I do have another problem with some very peculiar Formula behaviors. But I'll save that for a different thread. Thanks for the help.